# Authorization Header Checking before accessing any Servlet

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jwt

I buit a WebService with Java (Tomcat as WebServer), HttpServlet and I use JWT for security check.

So my server sent a JWT to my client when logging is successful, then this JWT will be sent in request headers for every request made by my client to my server. When my server will receive a request, he will get the JWT from the Authorization header and verify it to check if the action is allowed or not.

As this JWT will have to be verified for EVERY Crud operations in every Servlets in my WebService, I would like to know what is the best practice to avoid code duplicate. Is it a way to perform verification before accessing any Servlets or in a Servlet, a way to check it before doing any Crud operation or something ?

Comment: you can use filters for that https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html

Comment: Hello, i'll check a bit about filters, thanks for your reply :)